# Client side scripting can get server side HTTP callbacks?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

### Background

I have coded a system that have two parts: server code (ASP.NET MVC + C#) and client side (AngularJS application).

**The server side** make a calculation of many factors and when it find a "solution" - it's fire a HTTP callback to notify the user.

**The client side** is presenting a data which found so far by the server. This is the visualization of the data as a user report.

### What I have so far?

I currently have both side (server side + client side) coded. The way that HTTP callbacks is catched by the client side (step 3) this is the *weak* part which I think I should upgrade:

1. The data is visualize by AngularJS on the browser.
2. The server side find a solution (zero or more) and fire a HTTP callback to the webserver.
3. The webserver is getting the HTTP callback and notify the AngularJS app to update its view. This step is made by [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) which giving me the option to trigger JS code after server event.

### The Question

SignalR is giving me the ability to connect the client side (js) to server side events.

1. Is this possible to update the client side without using SignalR? Of-cause solution like "pull the web-server every N seconds for changes" are not recommended (performance).
2. Can you think about alternative to SignalR? Alternative system architecture?

Waiting to learn from you the best solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: [Server Sent Events](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manish1231/learn-html5-part-3-server-sent-events-apis/) ,  [WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875115(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SignalR *is* a WebSockets tool.

Comment: @Pointy SignalR is a tool that handles many of these tricks internally. Not only a websocket tool.

Comment: @LB right, that's true.

Comment: "best solution this problem"...you haven't told us a problem. What's wrong with your existing solution, exactly? SignalR is probably one of the better tools for this kind of thing, TBH. As pointed out, it's built on websockets, so using websockets directly would probably mean you need to do more work yourself, so not especially advantageous. Polling using ajax is a bad idea, as you already know, and that leaves server-sent events, which is perhaps a bit simpler than sockets, but has only limited browser support. AFAIK that pretty much covers your options.

Comment: If there's a specific, definable problem with some part of your solution which you'd like help with, then please state that clearly and include code and a problem description, and then people can help you fix that. The question as it stands currently is vague, doesn't describe a problem, and invites an opinion-based discussion of software architecture options, which is pretty much off-topic for SO, unfortunately.

Comment: What initiates this step -> The server side make a calculation of many factors and when it find a "solution". Is it initiated by the client?